# Implementing OR condition on jpa criteria join

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, criteria-api

I am creating a spring boot application and I want to implement an or condition in a JPA Criteria query such that the resulting query consists of:

```sql
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c ON t1.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID OR t1.DEST_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
```

(`t1` is another table `SALES_ORDER`)

Without using the JPA criteria API results in:

```sql
inner join customer customermo3_ on salesorder0_.customer_id=customermo3_.customer_id and salesorder0_.dest_id=customermo3_.customer_id
```

What I want is an OR condition.

Note that my field in the `SalesOrderModel` class is:

```java
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEST_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private CustomerModel customerModel;
```

My JPA Criteria code:

```java
Join<SalesOrderModel, CustomerModel> customerJoin = salesOrderRoot.join("customerModel", JoinType.INNER);
customerJoin.on(
        builder.or(
                builder.equal(salesOrderRoot.get("customerId"), customerJoin.get("customerId")),
                builder.equal(salesOrderRoot.get("destId"), customerJoin.get("customerId"))
        )
);
```

However the query ends up being

```sql
inner join customer customermo3_ on salesorder0_.customer_id=customermo3_.customer_id and salesorder0_.dest_id=customermo3_.customer_id and (salesorder0_.customer_id=customermo3_.customer_id or salesorder0_.dest_id=customermo3_.customer_id)
```

Comment: Not sure if you can even do this. When doing `join` the `ON` is automatically generated based on the metadata for the JPA object. Your mapping also looks weird, how can you have multiple join columns for 1 element, I would expect 2 fields for this.

Comment: @M.Deinum - one cannot. Bogus question.

Comment: @K.Nicholas What part of that question is bogus and why? Otherwise, feel free to improve it to make it not bogus

Comment: @M.Deinum it is possible to have multiple join columns, this results to an and condition in the on clause

Comment: @user14773854 Doesn't work. Please read quide on how to post a minimal reproducible question.

Comment: Yes it is possible to have multiple join columns but those only work if you have a multi column key in the other object. It won't work for OR, so yes there can be multiple join columns but not in an OR fashion.